# C#/WPF - Saving changes to MySQL

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am writing a small test app.  It's simply a XAML view with two text-boxes that are bound to a MySQL table.  I can read the data in just fine, but I don't know how to save the changes back and could do with some help:

XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding org_name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="139,9,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="339" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="{DynamicResource appFontSize}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding adr_one_postalcode}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="868,92,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110" FontSize="{DynamicResource appFontSize}" />
```

C#

```
//Initial variables
readonly MySqlConnection _con = new MySqlConnection(ClsVariables.StrDb);
readonly RecordReturn _rec = new RecordReturn();
MySqlCommand _cmd;
MySqlDataReader _dr;


private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _con.Open();
    var sqlText = string.Format("SELECT view_source.* FROM view_source WHERE view_source.contact_id = " + ClsVariables.IntId + ";");
    var sqlCmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlText, _con);
    using (var reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (reader.Read())
    {
    _rec.contact_id = ClsVariables.IntId.ToString();
    _rec.org_name = reader["org_name"] as string;
    _rec.adr_one_postalcode = reader["adr_one_postalcode"] as string;
    }
}
    _con.Close();
    DataContext = _rec;
}


private class RecordReturn
{
    public string contact_id { [UsedImplicitly] private get; set; }
    public string org_name { [UsedImplicitly] private get; set; }
    public string adr_one_postalcode { [UsedImplicitly] private get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: I just don't know how to save.  I'm quite new to working this way and most of the posts, I have found are a little over my head.

Comment: You know how to write an update statement right?

Comment: as in a query - sure, but there will eventually be numerous fields on this page and I really want to know the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could add button "save" and execute this code.

```
using(_con)
{
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Table SET col1 = @par1, col2 = @par2 WHERE id = @id", _con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@par1", TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@par2", TextBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", _selectedID);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Also, in loop in your code it should be `while(rdr.Read())`, not `if(rdr.Read())`.

Comment: Thank you for that - but if there were 50 fields on the View, would that still be the best way to do it?

Comment: This is not working for MySql, since this sample uses `SqlCommand` and `@` for parameters.

Comment: Oh, right, sorry.. Well I could suggest "UPDATE Table SET col1 = '"+TextBox1.Text+"' WHERE id = "+_selectedID+", but it isnt good idea because of sql injection.

Comment: Hi guys - any thoughts on my above comment?

Answer (score 0):

As you imply, if you have 50 fields (or 100, or 500 ...) then the manual approaches given above are really going to get dull (and error prone) real fast.

You may be a beginner, but I really recommend you have a look at two things: Entity Framework and MVVM.

1. The first provides your data access, and will turn the horrible select/update magic strings into LINQ queries and just updating properties on real class objects.
2. The second will show you how to bind an object that represents data to elements in your UI, such that when the UI changes the data held within properties on a class object also changes. You can then 'submit' these changes with EF and so streamline how you write changes to a database.

Comment: Scary yes, but definitely the right way to approach your problem :) EntityFramework has a provider for MySQL, so yes ... you'll be able to use LINQ against the collections created as part of the EF integration.